# Using shared SSL for login/admin

Tags: admin, login, ssl

I want to use SSL for login/admin.  However, since I'm using a shared server, my web host only provides a shared SSL.  That means instead of `https://www.regular-domain.com` I have to go to `https://servername.webhostname.com/~myusername/`, which throws Wordpress off since it expects everything to be under the regular domain.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [WP HTTPS plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-https/), it has a Shared SSL option. Also see [discussion here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-wordpress-https-what-is-the-purpose-of-the-shared-ssl-option).

Comment: I haven't been able to get that plugin set up correctly.  I've installed it, unchecked all options except for the Shared SSL option, put in my SSL-protected domain, and added `define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true)` to my _wp-config.php_.  When I try to go to the login page I'm redirected to `https://servername.webhostname.com/~myusername/~myusername/wp-login.php` (note the duplicate `~myusername`) and get a 404 page.

Comment: Sorry, i'm not using the plugin myself, yet...please contact the plugin maintainer. It looks like it's not picking up what you put into the Shared SSL Host field.